# LINQ selection based on collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question regarding c# and LINQ:

I have a class **items** (parent) that can have multiple **custom_fields** (child). The custom_fields class has 3 values: ID, Name, Value.

I want to filter based on the custom_field. For example, all items where custom_field color has the value red.

I am a bit lost in how to do the LINQ-query. I tried the following, but that is wrong.

```
items = items.Where(x => x.custom_fields.Where(y => y.Name == "color")
                                        .Any(z => z.Value == "red")
                   );
```

How do I write the correct query?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get all items with red color into your result

```
.Where(x => x.custom_fields.Where(y => y.Name == "color").Any(z => z.Value == "red"));
```

should be

```
.Where(x => x.custom_fields.Any(y => y.Name == "color" && y.Value == "red"));
```

Comment: That looks very good, but for some reason it leaves me with 0 items. Before the query I have many items. items is ENumerable and custom_fields ICollection. Most items have multiple custom_fields (color, size, etc.). Do you have an idea what could cause the problem?

Comment: @sebvst Your result should be `items` or `custom_fields`? Are there any `custom_fields` items with `Name == "color"` and `Value == "red"` in your database?

Comment: My query selects all `items` which have at least one `custom_fields` sub item which has `Name == "color"` and `Value == "red"`

Comment: You are right, it works. I had an issue with a blank. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming items is `IEnumerable<T>`

```
var redItems = 
    from item in items
    from custom_field in items.custom_fields
    where custom_field.Name == "color" && custom_field.Value == "red"
    select item;
```